# Javascript regex match different groups

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to replace different parts of a string with a word that's inside of every matching group. So, if I have this string:

```html
<td>{$phrase->getId()}</td>
<td>{$phrase['name']}</td>
<td>{$phrase['id']}</td>
```

I would like to be able to get the string:

```html
<td>id</td>
<td>name</td>
<td>id</td>
```

I tried this expression:

```regex
\{\$\w+(?:\['(\w+)'\]|->get(\w+)\(\))\}
```

but when I `input.replace(regex, "$1")` I get:

```html
<td></td>
<td>name</td>
<td>id</td>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replace with `$1$2` since you have used `|` or operator

like this : `input.replace(regex, "$1$2");`

for the first sentence the `Id` is coming inside the second capture group, thus it is not matching the first one.

Comment: I can't believe it was this easy, most answers I found were telling to remove the `|` but I need it, thanks.

Comment: @lulian I don't know why have you used the non capturing group.

Comment: To be able to alternate between the two variants.